# Lost my 3ds, trying to use citra, how do I get my physical roms onto pc?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Basically the title.

I had lost my Nintendo 3ds, and I've downloaded Citra 3ds emulator. I want to get the rom off of my ACNL cart, however I haven't found any sort of way to do it without the 3ds.

I'm not able to buy another 3ds.

What can I do?

Comment: sorry, but you must get your hands on a 3ds somehow. getting the files online is very possible but highly illegal, so dont go down that path.

Comment: Ray, I'm trying to transfer my game cart rom to the pc. Like a USB.

Comment: You need a 3ds.